# Implementing localization in DDD pattern - Infrastructure/Persistance Layer?

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, microservices, domain-driven-design

I'm working on a Blogging platform in .NET Core and one of the key requirements is to have different translations based on the user's selected language. It's clear to me that majority of this part belongs to the UI layer, but I want to let bloggers submit different translations of their posts by themselves.

So far I modified my `Domain` that it now contains the `Language` property and I also created `Localized` attribute to mark properties that are multilingual. In my approach I want to keep all localization-related logic in the `Infrastructure` layer so it saves/loads proper translations to/from another table containing translations for `Localized` properties automatically without the `Application` layer (or services) knowing about it.

I'm also implementing `UnitOfWork` pattern and normally I would use repositories through it, like in a following way: `UnitOfWork.BlogPosts.Add(post)` and after all operations are done: `UnitOfWork.CommitChanges()`, but I assume that now `UnitOfWork` would contain both repositories: for `BlogPost` and for `Localization` and the whole logic of saving/loading localized data would need to be implemented in a `UnitOfWork` so instead I would have to call a method that manages both repositories, like this: `UnitOfWork.AddBlogPost(post)` (also `IUnitOfWork` interface would require these methods).

So my question is: is it a good design appraoch and is `UnitOfWork` a proper place to implement such logic? I want to keep it as automated as possible and if it doesn't cause any issues that I'm currently not aware of - to keep it directly in a persistance layer.

Edit: My second idea would be to simply keep the two repositories in `UnitOfWork` and implement saving/loading `BlogPost` + `Localization` in an `Application` layer (in commands handlers and queries using CQRS pattern). But unfortunately this way I would have to implement the same logic for saving/loading for every command and query...